# How to find the maximum range of a parameter in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-matrix

For example, in the pandas library, there is a module named - 'plotting' which has a method - 'scatter_matrix', which in turn has a parameter - 'alpha'. According to the python documentation, alpha is used to set the transparency of points on a graph. But it does not tell me what range its value should be in.

Comment: Did you try the `help` command on it?

Comment: It didn't show the range though.

Comment: If you have a specific grievance about a question ban, try [meta]; vandalizing your question will only degrade your situation further.

Answer (score 0):

According to [pandas source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/84aa56bdb2c5163ff141a56f50d62617589d908f/pandas/plotting/_misc.py#L72) the `alpha` parameter is passed to matplotlib, so I assume it means the same as described there:

> alpha : float (0.0 transparent through 1.0 opaque)

This can be easily found in the [pyplot API docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).